# AS3 MovieClip not playing consistently

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, movieclip, autorelease

So at the beginning when my SWF loads up it also loads up a sequence of animated clips like so:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("clips/clip4.swf"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, clip4Loaded);
```

And my `clipLoaded` function is:

```
private function clip4Loaded(e:Event):void {
    clip4 = e.target.content as MovieClip;
}
```

The clip4 file being loaded in has a `stop()` at the first frame. Later in the game (clip4 is the "outro") I use:

```
clip4.gotoAndPlay(0);
clip4.addFrameScript(clip4.totalFrames - 1, clip4End);
```

However, the clip only seems to play about 25% of the time and all the other clips which I load the exact same way play fine. The only difference is that those clips get played fairly soon after they load which leads me to believe `clip4` is being autoreleased at some point but I really have no clue.

Comment: so you need to load a clip, stop it and then play once? what's `clip4End`? can you upload it anywhere?

Comment: `clip4End` is just a function that is called when the movie reaches the last frame. right now all it does is spit some data out through trace.

Answer (score 0):

strange - i've got a timeline-animated swf with `stop();` in the first frame and the following code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    /**
     *
     * @author www0z0k
     */
    [SWF(width='400', height='300', frameRate='30')]
    public class NewClass extends Sprite {
        private const URL:String = 'res/1.swf';
        private var spr:MovieClip;
        public function NewClass():void {
            var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
            ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onloaded);
            ldr.load(new URLRequest(URL));
        }

        private function onloaded(e:Event):void {
            spr = e.target.content as MovieClip;
            addChild(spr);
            spr.addFrameScript(spr.totalFrames - 1, function():void { x = x == 0 ? 100 : 0; } );
            spr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onclick);
        }

        private function onclick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            spr.gotoAndPlay(0);
        }
    }    
}
```

and it works exactly as it's written. 
could you please upload your `clip4.swf` anywhere (or test this code with it yourself)?

Comment: That is basically exactly how my code functions. Also, the swf itself doesn't matter. I have tried it with 24 different swf movie files and they all produce the same behavior. Sometimes it plays, most of the time it doesn't. After some further testing I'm pretty sure it has something to do with `gotoAndPlay` just... failing to play.

Comment: @ ingot86 - are you sure that function containing `gotoAndPlay` is called every time? did you try switching to next frame on `ENTER_FRAME` manually while animation has to be played?